# How can I export unformatted text from a rich edit control?

Tags: delphi

So I want to export all the lines to a .txt file when a button is pushed. I got it to work but it also adds some other stuff to the .txt file.

Code I used for the button `richedit1.Lines.SaveToFile('output.txt');`

Ok now lets say I typed this in the richedit

```
Line1 test
Line2 test
Line3 test
```

Then I press the button and i get this output

```
    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang7177{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
    \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs24 Line1 test\par
    Line2 test\par
    Line3 Test\par
    }
```

Is there any way to only show the lines in the richedit to the output.txt file?

Answer (score 7):

Set the [`PlainText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.PlainText) property of the rich edit control to `True` before calling `SaveToFile`.

The documentation for this property says:

> Controls whether the rich edit control treats the text as plain text or rich text when streaming to or from a file.
>
> To write the rich text in the control to a plain text file, set PlainText to true before streaming the text to a file. To ignore the rich text information encoded in a file, set PlainText to true before streaming the text to the control.
>
> To stream in the rich text attributes encoded in a file, or save the encoding of the rich text attributes to a file, set PlainText to false.

Comment: Note that property only applies when calling the RichEdit's `SaveTo...()` methods, nothing else.